# PYQT5: instantiating multiple QThread classes for independent timers

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have an application that keeps track of the time with a 1-second countdown timer that works perfectly:

```
class CDWorker(QtCore.QThread):
    sinout=  pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, ctrl):
        super(CDWorker,self).__init__()
        self.working = True       
        self.num = 0

 
################################ Trigger the controller callback on timer cycle        
    def timerEvent(self, ctrl, event):
        if len(ctrl.activeDF) != 0:
            ctrl.activeDF.apply(ctrl.timerPipeline, axis = 1)
            ctrl.getNearest()
            super().timerEvent(event)

        
######################## Spin up the 1-second timer to constantly update time
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()    
    def run(self, ctrl):
        while self.working == True:
            loop = QtCore.QEventLoop()
            ctrl.DF.apply(ctrl.callback1, axis = 1) 
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, loop.quit)
            loop.exec()
```

and I have a controller class that handles most of the heavy lifting in the app

```
class Controller:
    def __init__(self):
        self._app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self._model = Model()
        self._view = View(ctrl = self)
        self._view.show()

        cdTimer = QtCore.QThread()
        cdWorker = CDWorker(ctrl = self)
        cdWorker.moveToThread(cdTimer)
        cdWorker.run(ctrl = self)
        cdTimer.started.connect(CDWorker.run)
```

This all works perfectly and everything is good. However, now I need another class responsible for scheduling an http request on a 5 minute timer. Every attempt ive made so far to make another Qthread, QTimer, Qthreadpool, etc has either blocked the main eventloop, overridden the original timer, or was just ignored. Ive tried messing with the signal/slots and all too.

How can I get two classes with independent timers to trigger callbacks in my controller class?

Comment: Your code doesn't make a lot of sense. I'm actually surprised that it "works perfectly", because from what I can see you are *not* using threading at all. Why do you create an event loop there? What is `ctrl`? Why do you try to call an instance method using a class instead? If that is your actual code, not only that `cdTimer` thread doesn't get started, but it even gets garbage collected as soon as the `__init__` returns.

Comment: ctrl is a reference to the Controller class.  How Would you go about it instead?

Comment: I cannot give you an answer, as your code is really confusing. I suggest you to do some more research on QThread and do some experiments with **basic** tests (even with simple `time.sleep`). Then consider that: you should **never** try to directly access UI elements from an external thread (your code "works" because you're not using it as a thread, otherwise it would have most likely crashed); the `run()` of a QThread has *no* arguments (and you shall never call it explicitly) and trying to decorate it as a slot is pointless; read more about classes/instances, scope and garbage collection.

Comment: Wouldn't time.sleep block the main event loop

Comment: that's the point of using QThreads: they do *not* block the main event loop, as long as they are properly used: by implementing `run()` or moving a QObject to the thread. The thread is actually started with `start()` (as pointed out, `run()` must **not** be called, the thread will), and it will do anything it needs there without blocking the main event loop. Do research on basic "worker" implementations of QThread, try to understand what they do and read the docs. Threading is not immediate, but you can't expect to understand it by trying random things without knowing what they do.

Comment: Wow, that makes sense.